# ¿Impedir guardar 2 veces el formulario?

Tags: laravel

Como impido que un registro al ser guardado o actualizado, ya no pueda ser modificado, pues al dar atrás con el navegador se puede modificar la información. 
De momento llevo esto:

```
if($deposito = Deposito::lastest()
    ->where('create', '=','true'))
{
    return redirect()->route('depositos.index');
}
else if($deposito = Deposito::lastest()
    ->where('create','=','false'))
{
$deposito = new Deposito()
$deposito->noboleta = $request->noboleta
$deposito->monto = $request->monto
$deposito->id_tipo = $request->id_tipo
$deposito->id_banco = $request->id_banco
$deposito->id_estado = $request->id_estado
$deposito->fechaboleta = $request->fechaboleta
$deposito->detalles = $request->detalles
$deposito->id_usuario = Auth::id()
$deposito->create = true
$deposito->save()
return redirect()->route('depositos.index')
    ->with('success','Formulario Guardado');
}
```

}

Pero genera un error, al colocar ; o solo una coma.

Comment: Que versión de laravel estás usando ??

Comment: la versión 5.5LTS

Comment: Y cual es el error ? que dice ?

Comment: No me muestra error, independientemente si esta en true o false siempre me devuelve al index, ahora es mejor validar si ya existe dicho registro en base o impedir que se pueda volver atrás con el navegador?

Comment: Si en tu else vas a hacer otra condición deberías de colocar else if()

Comment: Me genera el siguiente error  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$deposito' (T_VARIABLE)

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70237/discussion-between-camilo-vasquez-and-user66297).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Conclusiones de lo hablado en el [Chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70237/discussion-between-camilo-vasquez-and-user66297).

Lo primero es asegurarnos que los registros no se puedan duplicar en nuestra base de datos, para eso usamos el método `firstOrCreate` que nos provee [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent), el **ORM** de **Laravel**

```
public function store(DepositoRequest $request) {
    Deposito::firstOrCreate([
    'noboleta' => $request->noboleta,
    'monto' => $request->monto,
    'id_tipo' => $request->id_tipo,
    'id_banco' => $request->id_banco,
    'id_estado' => $request->id_estado,
    'fechaboleta' => $request->fechaboleta,
    'detalles' => $request->detalles,
    'id_usuario' => Auth::id(),
    'create' => true
    ]);
}
```

Después debemos hacer una validación al momento de hacer el `update` por medio de un campo `booleano` para que el registro no pueda ser editado en casi de que fuera sido editado antes:

```
public function update(EditRequest $request, $id){ 
    $deposito = Deposito::findOrFail($id);

    if ($deposito->update) {
        return redirect()->route('depositos.autorizacion')->with('success', 'Deposito no puede ser actualizado');     
    }else{
        $deposito->id_estado = $request->id_estado; 
        $deposito->observaciones = $request->observaciones; 
        $deposito->autorizacion = Auth::user()->name; 
        $deposito->cod_autorizacion = Uuid::generate()->string; 
        $deposito->update = true; 
        $deposito->save(); 
        return redirect()->route('depositos.autorizacion')->with('success', 'Deposito actualizado'); 
    }
}
```

Yo no recomiendo tratar de bloquear la navegación del usuario para impedir que se devuelva (de hecho no se si es posible) pero el dañar la navegabilidad del sitio me parece poco óptimo para resolver este tipo de conflictos, mejor es aplicar alguna lógica de validación y por medio de mensajes emergentes hacerle saber al usuario lo que ha pasado.

Answer (score 0):

Al permitir al navegador volver atrás, corres el riesgo de guardar dos veces, o más, los mismos datos con id diferente, ya que el formulario no tiene un id que identifique los datos.

Se me ocurren dos opciones:

1.- Que a la hora de guardar los datos hagas una búsqueda en la base de datos por todos los campos del formulario (los que sean identificativos del registro) y en caso de que la consulta devuelva un registro haces un update o, simplemente, nada; en caso contrario creas un registro nuevo.

2.- No permitir volver atrás en el navegador mediante javascript.